# Inheritance and restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I need a control, like a Label in WPF. But this Label should be always autosized
(Width = Height = Auto) - user should not be able to modify it.

Also the BorderThinkness should be always = 0.

How can I do it in WPF? 
Is it possible to inherit such a label, in order that the children conserve that property (always AutoSized)?

Comment: As far as I know you can create a CustomControl an inherit from Label.  I have not built CustomControls in WPF yet (but in ASP.NET where you can do it like that). Otherwise maybe create your own control: [Creating a look less custom control in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14340/Creating-a-look-less-custom-control-in-WPF)

Comment: @Nicholas the question is hot how to create, question is how to implement the non-modification of Width and height. Should it be by overloadind or Shadowing the Wifdth, Height, BorderThickness properties?...

Comment: My first guess would be to make them readonly if you still want to access the values of the underlying baseclass in a readonly mode. if you try to set them in xaml it will generate a compiler error. so you'll have to shadow those properties

Answer (score 1):

Both the Width and the Height setters ultimately apply the bounds modification by invoking the virtual SetBoundsCore method.  Overriding this method should probably be your first choice candidate approach for the modification your are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UserControl that wraps a Label, and hardcodes 
`Width = Height = Auto` 
and 
`BorderThickness = 0`.

Something like:

```
<UserControl ...>
   <Label Width="Auto" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0" />
</UserControl>
```

Of course you'll have to expose the other properties through dependency properties.

EDIT: (shot in the dark)

You can try this out:

```
public class NewLabel : Label
    {
        private readonly object m_AutoValue;

        public NewLabel()
        {
            m_AutoValue = base.GetValue(NewLabel.HeightProperty);

            NewLabel.HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NewLabel), new PropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(
                    (dpo, dpce) =>
                    {
                        if (!dpce.NewValue.Equals(m_AutoValue))
                        {
                            ((NewLabel)dpo).ClearValue(Label.HeightProperty);
                        }
                    })));
        }
    }
```

I just made it up so it'll probably need some debugging, but you get the idea ;)

Comment: yeah... I'll have to expose all other properties via dependency properties... But maybe just overload the Width and Height properties in a new CustomControl that inherits Label?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot overload those properties

Comment: Attention: overload, not override! )

Comment: I thought you mistook overload for override, because you cannot "overload" properties either AFAIK )

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having an application-wide resource dictionary and defining a style?  Define it once, and you can use `<Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AutoSizeLabel}" />` wherever you need it.

In AppResources.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    >
    <Style x:Key="AutoSizeLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

In App.xaml

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="AppResources.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
```

---

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AutoSizeLabel}">MyLabel</Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This will work for that class, but... the title of the question is "Inheritance and restrictions", so I am afraid I can't inherit a style.